# Blazor server does not show meta tags from Headcontent

Tags: blazor-server-side, meta-tags

My Blazor server app needs to specify canonical urls to avoid duplicate content on search engines between for example 4moms.pt and [www.4moms.pt](http://www.4moms.pt)
Hence I am using next code on page component:

```
@page "/category"

<HeadContent>
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.4moms.pt/mamaroo" />
</HeadContent>
```

But looking at the page source I cannot see the metatag in the  section, and Google search console says the page is not indexed since there is duplicated content and canonical url is not specified.

Is there any issue with HeadContent component on Blazor server side?

Comment: Try this <HeadContent>
   <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.4moms.pt/mamaroo/"><meta property="og:site_name" content="canonical" />
</HeadContent>

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <HeadContent>
       <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.4moms.pt/mamaroo/">
       <meta property="og:site_name" content="4moms" />  
       <meta property="og:type" content="website">
       <meta property="og:title" content="4moms | Artigos de bebê de alta tecnologia. Redes,
<meta name="description" content="A 4moms® cria produtos para bebês inovadores e fáceis de usar que facilitam a vida dos padres. Compre nossa seleção de balanços, berços, cadeiras altas e muito mais.">
    </HeadContent>
```

Comment: Thanks Chinmay. Open graph tags within HeadContent are not displayed either. I guess Google crawler does not execute Blazor javascript so it is missing all content